# When I am trying to add github repo to a heroku app it throws "Internal Server Error"

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

When I am trying to add github repo to a heroku app it throws "Internal Server Error". The same thing is also happening to my other running app also. Is it a problem with the github account?

[image: Error Screen Shot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are facing seems related to the security issue reported on https://github.blog/2022-04-15-security-alert-stolen-oauth-user-tokens/

And based on this ongoing [incident](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413),

> As reported yesterday, revocation of all OAuth tokens from the Heroku Dashboard GitHub integration is complete. Until further notice, we will not issue OAuth tokens from the Heroku Dashboard. These actions, based on our current understanding of the issue, should prevent unauthorized access to your GitHub repositories.

> We will continue to work with GitHub to provide additional guidance on how to review your GitHub logs for evidence of exfiltration or malicious activity. Please reach out to security@salesforce.com with any information that may assist us with our ongoing investigation.
> Please continue to visit status.heroku.com for the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue a couple of days ago. To fix this issue for now, you can deploy with Git instead of using the GitHub integration. Check the following link for instructions depending on your app. You can either create a new one with the heroku cli or assign a remote to the local repo before deployment.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git